# Como compilar programas em C no Visual Studio 2019 sem abrir algum projeto ou solução?

Tags: c, compiladores, mingw, cmake

Sou novato na programação e estou tentando utilizar o Visual Studio 2019 para escrever códigos em C. Porém para isso preciso criar um projeto/solução dentro da IDE, algo que não me convém porque estou a todo momento criando novos arquivos para testar funções e resolver problemas e aparentemene, o Visual Studio compila uma solução inteira, não sendo possível executar arquivos .c separademente (pelo que eu entendi lendo alguns artigos é isso, se eu estiver errado, por favor me avise). Gostaria de executar meus códigos apenas navegando por pastas, mas infelizmente meus códigos não compilam.

Pesquisando, pude descobrir que é sim possível executar programs sem a necessidade de um projeto/solução (própio site da Microsft diz isso). Contudo, no artigo que li, não explicam como fazer isso. Soube também do CMake que faz a compilação do código mas não consegui de maneira alguma configurar para a minha máquina. Tentei também MinGW mas também não consegui configurá-lo para compilar meus códigos.

Como eu posso compilar e executar programas .c no Visual Studio 2019 sem um projeto/solução?

Comment: [Ver isso](https://fig.if.usp.br/~esdobay/c/gcc.html)

Comment: são não quser usar a IDE, instale um compilador e compile pela linha de comandos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Build Tools do Visual Studio 2019

Você pode usar o Visual Studio 2019 apenas para edição, se preferir, e compilar seus códigos utilizando as [Build Tools do Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).

Para saber como instalar e utilizar um compilador a partir de um programa que possibilite acesso ao sistema de arquivos do seu SO (acredito que seja o Windows) por linha de comandos (como o [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), por exemplo), tente [este artigo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160). Não é necessário criar um projeto através da IDE, pois quase sempre terá arquivos a mais que são proprietários da ferramenta, como arquivos de configuração. Você pode apenas criar um diretório com os arquivos `.c` e compilar um ou mais deles a partir da linha de comando.

#### Considerações

De experiência, tenho duas maneiras de compilar código em C. A primeira é [utilizando um compilador online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler). Me atende quando preciso apenas executar um pequeno bloco de código ou um programa simples. Edito o código nele mesmo ou no [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Para programas maiores, mais complexos e/ou que precisam ser compatíveis com mais de uma plataforma, utilizo o [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), compilando o código com o [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.